# Delete unused parent models

Tags: django

I have these two models:

```
Parent(models.Model):
   name=models.CharField(max_length=10)

Child(models.Model):
   parent=models.ForeignKey(Parent)
   name=models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

I am looking for an efficient way to remove parent's with no children. Currently, I am doing it with RAW SQL:

```
 from django.db import connection
 SQL="DELETE FROM app_parent WHERE app_parent.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM app_child"
```

Which is running two queries and I still want to use Django ORM. With ORM, as well, I am first getting list of children first then check if parent id exists there or not.

Is there a faster way of doing that?

Comment: Well this is actually still one query, but it has subqueries. It will however run in the same time complexity. We can speed it up a bit.

Comment: speed it up how @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## With a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

You can detect `Parent`s without a child, by `.filter(..)`ing with the `related_name`, and check if that relation `__isnull`.

So we can get a list of `Parent`s with *no* child by writing:

```
Parent.objects.filter(child__isnull=True).distinct()
```

The `.distinct()` is important here, since otherwise a parent can occur *multiple* times. Behind the curtains, Django will perform a query that looks like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `parent`.*
FROM `parent`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `child` ON (`parent`.`id` = `child`.`parent_id`)
WHERE (`child`.`id` IS NULL)
```

We can then `.delete()` those `Parent`s:

```
Parent.objects.filter(child__isnull=True).distinct().delete()
```

## With an `EXISTS` query

We can also work with an exists query:

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

Parent.objects.annotate(
    has_children=Exists(
        Child.objects.filter(parent=OuterRef('pk').values('id'))
    )
).where(has_children=False).delete()
```

So here we annotate every `Parent` with the fact whether or not a `Child` exists that has as `parent`, the `pk` of the `Parent`. We then `.filter(..)` on the fact that this annotation should be `False`.

This will result in a query like:

```
SELECT `parent`.*
FROM `parent`
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT `child`.`id`
    FROM `child`
    WHERE `child`.`parent_id` = `parent`.`id`
) = True
```

## Protected parent objects (through to other relations)

Note however that if the `Parent` is still referenced through other `ForeignKey`s, this might fail. If for example there is not only a child, but an `Uncle` relation, that refers to a `Parent`, then the `.delete()` could fail, since there are still `Uncle`s that refer to one or more `Parent`s without a child.

Comment: Thanks @willem Van Onsem. With a slight check for possible other related models, it was perfect and a little gain on speed.

Comment: @NieSelam: what about the second attemt (with `Exists`). Can you provide timings. Perhaps that would be nice for future readers.

Comment: Ok,let me try it out and paste my results.